# Adding halls to a production area by using GAMS?

Tags: layout, mathematical-optimization, coordinate-systems, fixed-point, gams-math

I have a grad project the topic is facility layout problem. I have an 75x95 sq meter area and I want to divide this area into 4 equal horizontal halls in order to allocation of the departments into these halls. There are 11 departments and 6 of them fixed (have predetermined locations). The rest of 5 is my decision variables in terms of length and width and space requirement. I cannot achieve dividing into halls and fixing the 6 departments which have predetermined locations. In GAMS how can I satisfy these constraints and definitions please help me. Thanks in advance. I defined 2 separate sets as fixed and unfixed departments.
For fixed departments I gave length and width of the relevant fixed department (i) and the area of the department (i) as parameters.
Then in variables I gave lower and upper bounds to length and width and area of unfixed  departments. I wrote non overlapping and space usage constraints.
I need your help about defining coordinates and dividing into halls.

Comment: Are all shapes rectangular? Square? Arbitrary? Do departments need accessibility corridors or can they be tightly packed? Are there compactness requirements for the departments? You need to show the code you have currently, and explain in much more detail what your constraints are, or this is off-topic.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.